# Redmine won't parse commits at all

Tags: redmine

(Even when I click "repository")
By this I mean: I made a commit with the following message:

```
screenshot now button

fixes #5
```

But I go to issue 5 and there's no reference to the commit, the
issue is still open, etc. Now I might think this was just a matter of
not setting up the automatic fetching, but: even if I go to the
repository for that project and view the commit, it doesn't link it. So
thinking maybe that didn't work, I went to [my url]/sys/fetch_changesets?key=[my key]. I saw just a
blank page. (I think that means it's working though, because when I took
off the key I saw "access denied".)
I'm on bitnami redmine 3.3.0-1, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is what the option "Allow issues of all the other projects to be referenced an fixed" is for. So I checked that, added "implements" as a fixing keyword, chose "resolved" as an applied status, and it works.